# Task planning algorithm

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, planning

I am looking for an algorithm to optimise the planning of tasks for one person in a week. Basically, each task would have a duration, a deadline and a preference score (basically how much you like doing it).

The optimisation would have to take into account the deadline, and the preference score. It seems to look a bit to a scheduling algorithm like Round-Robin, but I was wondering if there was another algorithm more adapted to this (or a well-known problem looking like it).

Comment: How would you take the preference scores into account? Deadlines I understand. But if a task has to be done, and has a fixed duration, how would the schedule be affected by different preference scores for that task?

Comment: Since deadlines would (obviously) override preferences, then first solve just for deadlines (with no preferences).  Then swap scheduling times without violating deadlines to optimize for preferences.

Comment: @RBarryYoung 's solution would work, you could also try to maximise the preference each day (so avoiding having a day full of boring tasks).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.